# theming "field collection" in node pages drupal 7

Tags: drupal, collections, drupal-7, field, drupal-theming

Drupal 7 "field collection" - If I want to theme a node page which has a "field collection", how do I go about separating the fields for customization? It seems thus far that only print render($content['field_collection_name']); outputs the result. The problem is that I can't figure out how to isolate the fields for theming.

I've created a node--content_type.tpl.php for this purpose but now stuck dead in the water. Would really appreciate someone saving the day for me.

**Solved as follows:**

Some of the links from below are really very helpful so do look, though, I've done something like this - 
Enter `dsm(print_r($variables));`on node to be rendered in my case `node--content_type.tpl.php` with field collection to find out the arrays and field values needed, then hide of course.

The styling part then would look something like this

`<div>class="class-for-label-here">My Desired Label - <span class="my-field-class-here"><?php print render($content['my_desired_field_here']['#items'][0]['value']); ?></span></div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a fairly good conversation about this same thing going on here:

http://drupal.org/node/1155752

Main answer is theming with template field--your-field-collection-name.tpl.php

After that you just need to figure out how to retrieve the contents from the arrays and/or objects!

Answer (score 2):

You may create create a custom field formatter for your field and use this formatter in the set-up of your content type.

Field formatter gives total control over the html output before it is rendered into the node template.

You can use this great tutorial to create a custom field formatter : http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/creating-new-field-formatters-drupal-7

Comment: more elegant, will definitely give this a try

Answer (score 1):

For a more normal, template based theming experience try the patch in http://drupal.org/node/1187990. Hopefully this will go into Field Collection 2.x.